# How to fix Lint's "[deprecation] locale in Configuration has been deprecated" warning

Tags: android, locale, deprecated, lint, android-7.0-nougat

Hopefully this is not a duplicate of the many other questions regarding the locale deprecated `context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale` call as I already fixed it.

How would I get rid of the Lint warning for the following code:

```
public static String toDateString(Context context, Date date)
{
    DateFormat format = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 ?
            DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, context.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0)) :
            DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
    return format.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use property directly.

See [getLocales](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#locale)

Comment: That's what I'm doing for API >=24. From your link: "If only the primary locale is needed,getLocales().get(0) is now the preferred accessor."

Comment: I meant I'm not using it directly

Comment: @PIXP I noticed the second branch:DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);  used property directly

Answer (score 0):

First check your current version and use deprecated one. Try this,

```
    Locale locale;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
      locale = this.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
    } else{
      locale = this.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    }
```

2. You can just use `Locale.getDefault()`

Comment: Your first solution is identical to my code. I'm checking on the second one now.

Comment: You can try this for more details `Resources resources = context.getResources();
Locale locale = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N
        ? resources.getConfiguration().getLocales()
            .getFirstMatch(resources.getAssets().getLocales())
        : resources.getConfiguration().locale;`